# Issue with compiling Arduino IDE sketch, gets * multiple definition of `__vector_15' * error

Tags: c++, arduino, header-files, arduino-ide

I got this sketch from internet and am trying to implement the same code. Source of sketch files:
*https://github.com/Robin61/Arduino-Pixy2-Dobot-Magician-Pick-and-Place*
*https://github.com/charmedlabs/pixy2/raw/master/releases/arduino/arduino_pixy2-1.0.3.zip*

I am trying to integrate Pixy2 with a 4 DOF Robotic Arm named *Dobot Magician*. This Robotic arm can be controlled via Arduino Mega microcontroller as well (By default, it is controlled using a software "*DobotStudio*" provided by Dobot itself).

Tutorial Source:
*https://uptimefab.com/2019/10/02/how-to-make-a-robot-vision-system-with-the-pixy-2-camera/*

When I try to upload the *Grab_Parts.ino* to the Arduino Mega, it gives the following error:

> libraries\Pixy2\ZumoBuzzer.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `buzzerSequence': (.text+0x0): multiple definition of` __vector_15'
> sketch\FlexiTimer2.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> exit status 1
> Error compiling for board Arduino Mega or Mega 2560.

I want to sort this issue as soon as possible. I am a beginner level user of Arduino boards and IDE. Please do comment if the issue is not clear enough or any information is missing. This is my first time using stackoverflow community as well.

Answer (score 0):

**

### Solved the issue

**

The *FlexiTimer2.cpp* file uses timer2 and the *ZumoBuzzer.cpp* file used `timer2` or `timer4`. I figured the cause of the error is when both the files use same timer. Hence, I commented out all the lines in *ZumoBuzzer.cpp* that is related to `timer2`, so that it uses `timer4` by default. After doing this, it compiled successfully without error. Hope this will be helpfull to anyone in future!